# Can't stop UIView animation in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewanimation

This is my animation code:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 1, options: [.repeat], animations: {
        self.micButtonOuterRing?.frame = CGRect(x: (self.originalOuterRingFrame?.origin.x)! - 30, y: (self.originalOuterRingFrame?.origin.y)! - 30, width: (self.originalOuterRingFrame?.width)! + 60, height: (self.originalOuterRingFrame?.height)! + 60)
        self.micButtonOuterRing?.alpha = 0
        self.micButtonOuterRing?.layer.cornerRadius = (self.micButtonOuterRing?.frame.width)! / 2
    }, completion: { _ in
        self.micButtonOuterRing?.frame = self.originalOuterRingFrame!
        self.micButtonOuterRing?.alpha = 1
    })
```

I am trying to stop it when I press a button so I run the following:

```
@IBAction func micButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {

    micButtonOuterRing?.layer.removeAllAnimations()

}
```

But the animation keeps going. I know the `micButtonPressed` function works because I added a print statement and it worked. Can somebody help?

Comment: Try logging on the code that starts the animation too. Maybe your button does both.

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39443163/remove-animation-in-swift)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove animation in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39443163/remove-animation-in-swift)

Comment: Also check to see if micButtonOuterRing is nil.

Comment: @Xcoder no it isn't

Comment: @matt micButtonOuterRing is not nil

Answer (score 1):

Use [UIPropertyAnimator](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewpropertyanimator) instead; its designed to let you pause, [stop](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewanimating/1649750-stopanimation), reverse, etc. and the syntax is almost exactly the same as the old UIViewAnimation Methods.

Comment: i did used the `UIPropertyAnimator` but now the animation does't repeat, this is my code: `self.micRingAnimation = UIViewPropertyAnimator.runningPropertyAnimator(withDuration: 1, delay: 1, options: [.repeat], animations: {}, completion: { _ in }`

Comment: if you want to use repeat then set UIView.setAnimationRepeatCount( Float.greatestFiniteMagnitute) in the animation block,  alternatively wrap the animation call in a function and call that function in the completion handler to kick off a new animation when the current one finishes.

Comment: its really weird... the animation still doesn't stop. Does it have anything to do with the fact that i'm starting the animation is the `viewDidLayoutSubviews`?